# How can I install python packages in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to run a model written in Python and packaged in Docker. The model is available here: https://github.com/pennsignals/chime_sims

The model has a requirements.txt file and a number of python files. Requirements file is supposed to install a number of python packages, including configargparse. The docker file runs, but when it gets to the python code that uses configargparse, I get an error that such a package does not exist.

I added a line that I think should install it:

```
RUN pip -m install --upgrade configargparse
```

and then I import it in the python code. But I still get an error stating that no such package exits.

Here is the Docker code:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /chime_sims
RUN conda update -yq -n base -c defaults conda

RUN conda create -yq -n chime_sims python=3.7 pip pandas matplotlib scipy numpy seaborn
COPY ./requirements.txt .
FROM python
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip -m install --upgrade configargparse
RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt .

RUN py -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And here is the list from requirements.txt:
ConfigArgParse
configargparse
gitpython
seaborn
numpy
pandas
gvar
lsqfit

I suspect I'll have problems installing gvar and lsqfit if I ever get configargparse to work. I had trouble installing those packages outside of docker, but it finally worked.

Any ideas on how I can fix it?
thank you,
i.

Comment: The line `RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt .` is overriding the requirements file with what's currently installed, so the next install line effectively does nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I blocked that line, but I still get the same error:

Comment: chime_sims-chime_sims-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
chime_sims-chime_sims-1  |   File "/chime_sims/_02_munge_chains.py", line 5, in <module>
chime_sims-chime_sims-1  |     from configargparse import ArgParser
chime_sims-chime_sims-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configargparse'
chime_sims-chime_sims-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
chime_sims-chime_sims-1  |   File "/chime_sims/_01_GOF_sims.py", line 14, in <module>
chime_sims-chime_sims-1  |     from configargparse import ArgParser
chime_sims-chime_sims-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Comment: The mix of `conda` and `pip` commands doesn't seem right to me; I'd probably try to stick to one packaging system or the other (`pip` is easier to use in Docker).  At the second `FROM` line the entire image build process starts over and that's probably not what you want.